# RegEx how to negate a match based on a character in a specific position

Tags: python, regex, sas, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Please note: I'm programming in Python (version 3.6), but would also like to port these regexes to SAS as well.

The large picture here is that I'm working with a SAS log, and I want to exclude lines printed to the log that are from %include statements. Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish would look like this:

```
54210      proc sort data=inds out=outds;
```

And the lines that I DON'T want will look like this:

```
33406     +%global  var1 var2 var3;
```

The key is that the 11th character will be a '+', but there will always be a group of numbers to the left followed by a group of spaces, whose length will ultimately be 11 spaces - *unless* it's an %include line, which I want to exclude.

What I have so far is this:

```
^[0-9]{1,11} (?! {2,10}\+)
```

This has worked to grab what I want exactly from the logs that I've tested, but it's far from right. The easy way out would be using this expression:

```
^[0-9]{1,11} {3,10}
```

And then add an extra condition that will ignore the line if the 11th character is a '+', but can I do this in a single regex? I came across lookaheads/lookbehinds working on this, but the problem is that the first matched group can vary in length, which moves around where the '+' would be expected - so is there a way that I can match a group within a set length, and *then* negate the match if it's followed by a character?

Comment: The `^[0-9]{1,11} {3,10}` already ensures the 11th char is not a `+`

Comment: Not quite - that expression will still match:

    `33406     +%global  var1 var2 var3;`

And this is because it the `{3,10}` will match any group of 1 to 10 numbers followed by 3 spaces, so the width of the match will differ. So it can still match:

    `1    +`
    `12     +`
    `1234     +`

Comment: So, you should be looking for `^(?!.{10}\+)[0-9]{1,11} {3,10}`, right? See https://regex101.com/r/k2q5Ka/1

Comment: Yes! That works quite well! I was struggling with the lookahead/lookbehinds, since I tried to use a lookbehind, but that was dependent on where the spaces ended. I can see this strictly targets that `+` at character 11. I'd still love to lock the second portion, after the lookahead, to strictly catch N numbers followed by  M spaces, where N + M == 1, but I might be asking too much.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain the *lock the second portion, after the lookahead, to strictly catch N numbers followed by M spaces, where N + M == 1* part? Do you mean you want to only match a chunk of digits or spaces that in sum are 10? I think some two-three examples with expected outputs for each would help.

Comment: In the SAS log files, the lines I'm looking for will always be a line counter, followed by spaces - with a total length of 11 before any other characters should be found. So - look at these https://regex101.com/r/m24BZk/2

Comment: Try `^(?!.{10}\+)(?=[\d ]{11}(?! ))\d+ +`, see https://regex101.com/r/qp44lN/1

Comment: This is near perfect and actually - you can take out the initial negative lookahead. see https://regex101.com/r/qp44lN/3. the rest of it actually already compensates for the fact that there can't even be a `+` in that group. There's only one more potential situation I see, which is in that link. If you have spaces between numbers, it'll still match the first portion. Like `1 2 4      `. But this already significantly decreases the risk of improper matches.

Comment: Your question is unclear, sorry.

Comment: To be clear, I think what you've given me is very sufficient, so I think this is a very satisfactory answer. But see the last line in https://regex101.com/r/qp44lN/4. If a) the string is at least 11 characters, b) it starts with a number, and c) that number is followed by a space, there can be a second number in the first 11 characters and it will still match. At this point I'm just curious if this expression can be infallible.

Comment: I start suspecting you just need [`^\d+ +(?<=.{11})`](https://regex101.com/r/hl8n4e/1).

Comment: That looks good to me - I had tried a look-behind like that but you fixed the first portion, and that locks it down. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d+ +(?<=.{11})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hl8n4e/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+ +` - 1+ digits and then 1+ spaces
- `(?<=.{11})` - a positive lookbehind check that requires exactly 11 chars immediately to the left of the current location.

Comment: Just wanted to add something here from your comments on the original question (since this addresses my problem, but my question was to negate a match based on a character in a specific position), this expression successfully negates the match based on the position of the `+`: `^(?!.{10}\+)(?=[\d ]{11}(?! ))\d+ +`, where the initial negative look-ahead `^(?!.{10}\+)` targets the `+` in position 11. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^[0-9\s]{,11}\+` for discarding unwanted logs. It matches up to 11 digits and/or spaces followed by a `+` (which seems to be the pattern for unwanted items). In case you want to negate the match you can simply do `not re.match(...)`.

Using a lookahead you can refuse strings that contain a `+` within their first 11 characters and then match the desired pattern: `^(?=[^+]{11})[0-9]{1,11} {3,10}`.

```
(?=      # Look ahead and assert equal that ...
   [^+]  # ... anything but a plus ...
   {11}  # ... matches the following 11 characters.
)
```

Comment: This helps, but it's still not _quite_ where I want to be, because it will always be numbers, followed by spaces. This allows the numbers and spaces to be interchangeable. And I specifically want to match, but negate the match if the + is character 11. So essentially in this context, it's important that I match something like `54210      proc sort data=inds out=outds;`, but don't match `33406 +%global var1 var2 var3;`.

Comment: @MichaelStackhouse Does that mean the `+` is always at 11th position? Then what prevents you from capturing it and checking the corresponding group (or even simpler `string[10] == '+'`)? You can use a lookahead to assert that none of the first 11 characters is a `+` (see my updated answer). Does that help you? In any case you could use two regular expressions, one for "whitelisting" wanted logs and one for "blacklisting" unwanted ones and then do `if not blacklisted and whitelisted: ...`.

Comment: I'm _excluding_ lines that have a + in the 11th position, but that's just a simple reversal of the `?=` to `?!` or `!=` you listed above. And yes what you replied is quite similar to what Wiktor answered in the comment thread on my original question, and that works out. So yes I can use a strategy like that. Also, yeah I can simply add a second condition, but for my own learning benefit I wanted to try to wrap this all into a single expression. The part I'm struggling with the most is you can see in the comment thread above.

Comment: I saved an expression and example strings to test on in the link here: https://regex101.com/r/m24BZk/2

Answer (score 0):

Rather than regex filtering, have you considered setting appropriate logging options in your SAS code so that lines from %include statements aren't logged in the first place? i.e. set `option nosource2;` at the start of your program.

Documentation:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000279225.htm

Comment: I have no control over this with my client, as all of the log options are preset in their autoexec (coincidentally, the lines I'm trying to filter out) and required defined by their SOPs. They have a lot more on than I'd like to see.